# Prevent duplicates across multiple executions of copying records back into source table while changing one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I want to select `CustomerID`, `OrderTypeID`, and `LoanNumber` from `tblOrder` and insert it with a new `OrderTypeID` but same `CustomerID` and `LoanNumber`.
My query does that but it duplicates the values, every time the query is executed it duplicates the rows.

```
insert into tblOrder (CustomerID, OrderTypeID, LoanNumber)
Select o.CustomerID,3, o.LoanNumber
from tblOrder as o
where o.OrderTypeID = 1;
```

this is what the query does:

OrderID 9 - 12 are duplicates or OrderID 5 - 8. The query was executed 2 times hence the records got duplicated.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: MERGE tblOrder AS dst
USING tblOrder AS src
ON dst.CustomerID = src.CustomerID AND dst.OrderTypeID = src.OrderTypeID AND dst.LoanNumber = src.LoanNumber
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (CustomerID, OrderTypeID, LoanNumber)
VALUES (src.CustomerID, 3, src.LoanNumber);

Comment: tried MERGE but it says 0 records affected .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first, and most important, issue here is *not* that your query inserts duplicates; it is that your table *allows* it to happen in the first place. Hence, you first need to create a UNIQUE INDEX on those 3 fields to disallow duplicates.

The second issue is how to handle the situation of when an operation attempts to insert a duplicate. You have two main choices:

1. You can check for the record's existence first and skip the INSERT if it is found, or
2. You can set the UNIQUE INDEX to "ignore" duplicates in which case you don't need to check first as the operation will silently fail, with just a warning that the duplicate was not inserted.

---

If you pick **Option #1** (check first), then:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_tblOrder_CustomerID_OrderTypeID_LoanNumber]
    ON [tblOrder]
    ( [CustomerID] ASC, [OrderTypeID] ASC, [LoanNumber] ASC );
```

And then:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblOrder (CustomerID, OrderTypeID, LoanNumber)
  SELECT o.CustomerID, 3, o.LoanNumber
  FROM   tblOrder as o
  WHERE  o.OrderTypeID = 1
  AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM tblOrder tmp
                     WHERE tmp.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                     AND   tmp.OrderTypeID = 3
                     AND   tmp.LoanNumber = o.LoanNumber);
```

If you pick **Option #2** (don't check), then:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_tblOrder_CustomerID_OrderTypeID_LoanNumber]
    ON [tblOrder]
    ( [CustomerID] ASC, [OrderTypeID] ASC, [LoanNumber] ASC )
    WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

And then:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblOrder (CustomerID, OrderTypeID, LoanNumber)
  SELECT o.CustomerID, 3, o.LoanNumber
  FROM   tblOrder as o
  WHERE  o.OrderTypeID = 1;
```

---

Example of how `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` behaves:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #IgnoreDuplicateTest (Col1 INT);
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_#IgnoreDuplicateTest_Col1]
    ON #IgnoreDuplicateTest
    ( [Col1] ASC )
    WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);

INSERT INTO #IgnoreDuplicateTest (Col1) VALUES (1);
-- (1 row(s) affected)

INSERT INTO #IgnoreDuplicateTest (Col1) VALUES (1);
-- Duplicate key was ignored.
-- (0 row(s) affected)

INSERT INTO #IgnoreDuplicateTest (Col1)
 SELECT tmp.val
 FROM (VALUES (1),(2)) AS tmp(val);
-- Duplicate key was ignored.
-- (1 row(s) affected)

SELECT * FROM #IgnoreDuplicateTest;

-- Col1
--    1
--    2
```

Answer (score 9):

this may helps you

Here I am checking the values present(which are in variables) are present in table or not, if present leave else insert

```
 Declare @claimid int, @subscriber int, @qualifyinginformation int
set @claimid = '1000008'
set @subscriber = '1'
set @qualifyinginformation = '1'

If Exists (Select * from test1 where claimid = @claimid and subscriber=@subscriber and qualifyinginformation=@qualifyinginformation )
begin
     print ('The Value already Exist')
 end
else
 begin
   Insert into test1 (claimid,subscriber,qualifyinginformation) values (@claimid,@subscriber,@qualifyinginformation)
select * from test1
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this answer relates to the actual question and not just the title?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky This answer addresses the title very well and it saved my time :-)

Comment: @Rauf I never suggested that this answer didn't address the _title_. I was saying that this answer does not answer the _question_ itself, which is _not_ about simply preventing duplicates. The question is much more specific. I tried updating the title years ago to hopefully reduce confusion, but it was still too vague, so I just updated it again to (hopefully) more accurately reflect what this question is really about. That being said, I'm glad this answer was able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
CREATE TABLE tblOrder(
    OrderID     INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    CustomerID  INT,
    OrderTypeID INT,
    LoanNumber  INT
)
INSERT INTO tblOrder VALUES
(1, 1, 45584565),
(1, 1, 45566856),
(1, 1, 45565584),
(1, 1, 45588545)

INSERT INTO tblOrder( CustomerID, OrderTypeID, LoanNumber)
SELECT
    o.CustomerID,
    3,
    o.LoanNumber
FROM tblOrder o
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblOrder
    WHERE
        CustomerID = o.CustomerID
        AND OrderTypeID = 3
        AND LoanNumber = o.LoanNumber
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertName] (
    @empname varchar(25),
    @email varchar(25)
)
AS
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'True'
        FROM
            Employee
        WHERE      
            EmployeeName = @empname
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'This record already exists!'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT into Employee(EmployeeName, EmailId) VALUES(@empname,@email)    
    END

EXEC [InsertName]   
   'Darshil','darshil@gmail'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, could you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you look for ? Make sure

```
Create table #temp(OrderID int, CustomerID int,  OrderTypeID int, LoanNumber int)
INsert into #temp values(1  , 1  , 1  , 45584565)
INsert into #temp values(2 ,  1 ,  1 ,  45566856)
INsert into #temp values(3  , 1  , 1 ,  45565584)
INsert into #temp values(4  , 1  , 1  , 45588545)

select * from #temp



UPDATE TE
SET  CustomerID=tab.CustomerID,OrderTypeID=3,LoanNumber=tab.LoanNumber
FROM #temp TE inner join
(Select o.OrderID,o.CustomerID,3 tt, o.LoanNumber
from #temp as o
where o.OrderTypeID = 1)tab

ON TE.OrderID = tab.OrderID

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Comment: this query updates current row with OrderType =3, i want a new row with Same CustomerID, and LoanNumber but OrderType 3

Comment: is your OrderId is Identity column ??  then your result gives correct ansewer for me

Answer (score -1):

> After you set the primary key on some column name, it will check for
>   duplicate entries on that column name and if found simply ignore the
>   duplicate data.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO db_name.table_name(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
```

Comment: Hello. I don't like down-voting someone who is new, but this question is specific to SQL Server, yet this answer is entirely invalid for SQL Server. There is no `IGNORE` option on an `INSERT` statement in SQL Server. Please see the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql